Problems parsing XML with pugixml
Using pugixml, and C++, I can't parse the following to get Value and Result:
case #1 <Response> Value="HERE" Result="1" </Response>
Is this xml format considered acceptable xml?
If so, how can it be parsed using pugixml?
This parses:
case #2:   <Response Value="HERE" Result="1" /> ,
I can get to Value and Result as attributes in case #2.
Unfortunately I can't control the incoming format of xml string.
I've tried this:
const char* xml_string = "<Response> Value='Here' Result='1' </Response>";

pugi::xml_document doc;
pugi::xml_parse_result result = doc.load_string(xml_string);

if (!result) {
    std::cerr << "XML parsing error: " << result.description() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

pugi::xml_node Response = doc.child("Response");

if (!Response) {
    std::cerr << "Error: Root element 'Response' not found" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

std::cout << "Element name: " << Response.name() << std::endl;

for (pugi::xml_attribute attr :Response.attributes()) {
    std::cout << "Attribute: " << attr.name() << "=\"" << attr.value() << "\"" << std::endl;
}

I was expecting to see Value and Result with their corresponding values "HERE" and "1".

please show a [mre], your code doesn't compile

This is an invalid C++ code. The xml_string contains an invalid example XML, <Response> does not have attributes. You might want Response.value().

The xml_string is a representation of  a string I have incoming.  My guess was that it didn't have an attribute.   If that's the case, how can it be parsed using pugixml?

btw, I changed to a format that compiles and runs by changing the double to single quotes.

Value='Here' Result='1' is a string value, it's returned by Response.value() and not parsed by pugixml.

Yea, that's the problem.  Is there a way to parse it using pugi or do I need to revert to straight C and strstr()?

You could take the tag text, wrap it in a <Response ... /> tag and hand that string to Pugixml. Of course it wholly depends on the original tag's contents being a valid set of XML attributes.

yes, as Value and Result aren't XML attributes, no XML parser will do anything other than give them to you as a string

No XML parser will read these two items like you want them, since they are not attributes -- they are just the content of the <Response> tag. Access that, and you'll get exactly the string that's inside your <Reponse>; that's as far as an XML parser will go.

The answer of Botje worked well; clever idea.
(print the node child_value, wrap the text in a proper xml tag and send that to pugxml)
thank you Botje
